# Graph into graph with arrows

Tags: arrows, graphs

I'm using `tikzpicture` and I have some graphs, but I want some graphs with arrows. Is there any simple syntax change for that?

My Graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
         \begin{scope}
           \draw (4,0) node[label=below:5] {};
...
         \end{scope}
         \draw 
...
         (4,4) -- (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi Bene, welcome to TeX.sx. You can mark code by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button. I've edited your question accordingly. I've also removed the greeting from the beginning of your question, which is just the style used on this site.`

Comment: If I understand you correctly change `\draw` to `\draw [->]` or `\draw [<-]`. There are also more arrow heads available. See the [PGF/TikZ manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 9):

As Martin commented you can use `[->]` in the `\draw` command to add an arrow. Different arrow style can also be specified by using options such as: `-stealth`, `-latex`, etc..  Here are a few types:

[image]

See **Section 23 Arrow Tip Library** for a list of the various ones that are already available.  Adding `\usepgflibrary{arrows}` to your preamble provides a large variety of built in arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}% for more options on arrows

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw [green, ->          ] (0,8.0) -- (1,8.0);
\draw [blue,  -stealth    ] (0,7.5) -- (1,7.5) node [right] {stealth};
\draw [red,   -latex      ] (0,7.0) -- (1,7.0) node [right] {latex};
\draw [cyan,  -to         ] (0,6.5) -- (1,6.5) node [right] {to};
\draw [brown, -triangle 60] (0,6.0) -- (1,6.0) node [right] {triangle 60};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Since you included a `scope` in your example, it should be noted that you can also specify the arrow to be used for each line in a `scope` as well by adding that to the options to `\begin{scope}`. In the following all lines will have `-stealth` arrows. Adding `-` will disable the arrow for a particular line:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}% for more options on arrows

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\begin{scope}[-stealth]
    \draw [blue   ] (0,7.5) -- (1,7.5) node [right] {stealth};;
    \draw [red,   ] (0,7.0) -- (1,7.0) node [right] {stealth};
    \draw [brown,-] (0,6.5) -- (1,6.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```