# Adding Arrows to Lines Drawn in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am using the markup listing from [Draw comparison lines between two listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40714/draw-comparison-lines-between-two-listings).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\lstset{
    frame=single,
    mathescape % Allows escaping to (La)TeX mode within $..$
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Original code}]
  1 $\tikzmark{L1line1}$
  2
  3
  4 $\tikzmark{L1line4}$
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Code after insertion of detour}]
 $\tikzmark{L2line1}$ 86
 $\tikzmark{L2line4}$ 4
\end{lstlisting}
   \end{minipage}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[color=red] ($(L1line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$) -- ($(L2line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$);
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[color=blue] ($(L1line4)+(0pt,0.7ex)$) -- ($(L2line4)+(0pt,0.7ex)$);
\end{document}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

I want to add arrowheads on the end of each line - 4 in this case. I've attempted to edit the markup with the help of [Drawing Arrows in Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/drawing-arrows-in-tables) but haven't been able to progress much. Could someone please show me how arrowheads could be plotted in this case?

Comment: Just add `->` to the options to the `draw` commands at the end. That is, change `color=red` to `color=red, ->`. Same for the other.

Comment: Adding `->` to the `\draw[color=red,->]` command in `\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[color=red] ($(L1line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$) -- ($(L2line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$);` should do the trick.

Comment: I simplified your code to make the question more widely applicable.  Please have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that so you can do that yourself for your next questions. Note that the code probably still isn't a MWE because `listings` isn't even necessary for the issue with arrowheads. Reducing your code not only helps other users here who might help you, but also helps you understand your problem better.

Comment: @wh1t3: I think your comment is an answer- I would vote for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A @whlt3 mentioned in the comments, adding the `->` option to the draw command will produce an arrow. There are different arrow option available, and below I have used `-latex` as I think that looked better in this case. In the linked question [Drawing Arrows in Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/drawing-arrows-in-tables) the arrow style `-triangle 45` was used so may not have been obvious. A few of the arrow types are mentioned at [Graph into graph with arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/graph-into-graph-with-arrows/34127#34127), but many more are available -- see the `TikZ/PGF` documentation for more arrow options.

However, in this case I would also recommend that you also adapt a slightly different syntax so that you can specify the `out` and `in` angle for the line so that provide flexibility in case the straight line would overlap some other code to yield:

[image]

### Notes:

- This requires two runs. Once to determine the begin and end point of the lines, and the second to draw them.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\lstset{
    frame=single,
    mathescape % Allows escaping to (La)TeX mode within $..$
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Original code}]
  1 code $\tikzmark{L1line1}$
  2 some longer code here
  3 some longer code here
  4 more code$\tikzmark{L1line4}$
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Code after insertion of detour}]
 $\tikzmark{L2line1}$ 86
 $\tikzmark{L2line4}$ 4
\end{lstlisting}
   \end{minipage}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[color=red,thick,out=0,in=160] ($(L1line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$) to ($(L2line1)+(0pt,0.7ex)$);
\tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[color=blue,thick,out=0,in=200] ($(L1line4)+(0pt,0.7ex)$) to ($(L2line4)+(0pt,0.7ex)$);
\end{document}
```