# arrows with tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I use tikz, and try draw a directed graph with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                  
\node[draw, circle] (1) {1};                                                         
\node[draw, circle] (2) [ right of=1] {2};                                           
                                                                                     
\path (1) edge (2);                                                                  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and get

[image: ss]

how I can get this ? (with arrow)

[image: ss1]

#### Edit

I try with

```
\path[->] (1) edge (2);
```

but I get

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.403     \path[->] (
                     1) edge (2);
```

Comment: Just add `[->]` after `\path`. See the manual for various arrow style options.

Comment: As @percusse said.  Possible Duplicate: [Graph into graph with arrows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/graph-into-graph-with-arrows/34127#34127)

Comment: Your code `\path[->] (1) edge (2);` works fine for me...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`spanish` babel's option declares `<` and `>` active characters to write something like `<<Hello>>` and obtain french quotes. This behavior clashes with `TiKZ` arrow form `[->]`.
The way to deactivate `<>` is `\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}`, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                  
\node[draw, circle] (1) {1};                                                         
\node[draw, circle] (2) [ right of=1] {2};                                           

\path[->] (1) edge (2);                                                                  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works as expected. I've [found](http://listserv.rediris.es/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1004&L=ES-TEX&F=&S=&P=27427) this solution in [CervanTeX](http://www.cervantex.es/) (spanish TUG) forums:

**Update for `TiKZ 3.0`**

`TiKZ 3.0` includes a new `babel` library (pgfmanual section 42) which avoid this kind of problems. Using it, is not necessary to use `es-noquoting` option any more. You can even have `spanish` quotes inside nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                  
\node[draw, circle] (1) {<<1>>};                                                         
\node[draw, circle] (2) [ right = of 1] {<<2>>};                                           

\path[->] (1) edge (2);                                                                  
\end{tikzpicture}

<<Hola>>
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if `babel-greek` declares something which might cause problems even with 3.0? I'm having trouble reproducing in a MWE but in my real code, merely adding `greek` to the `babel` options causes compilation to fail and I've no idea why.

Comment: @cfr I've never used `babel-greek`. What problem do you have? Is it in a TiKZ graphic? Or in normal text but loading TiKZ3.0? What's shown in .log file? I'm sure you understand that with this kind of description is difficult to help you.

Comment: Sure. It was just a query in case you happened to know of any similar issue with `babel-greek`. (Yes, it is a TikZ graphic and it is something about that plus loading `babel-greek`, even if no Greek is included in the graphic or anywhere in the document.) But asking was rather a long shot. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this old Mail from Till Tantau I found when googling your added error message is helpful somehow: [tex.pgf.user list](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.pgf.user/2007-04/msg00027.html).

There seems to be an issue with the use of `<` and `>` as ative characters in some languages in TeX. The solution is supposedly (quoting Till)

> [...] using `\shorthandsoff` (or something similar) inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: maybe this is my problem, I use spanish package

Comment: @JuanPablo This is to show you how important a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is.

Answer (score 3):

A follow-up on the possible interference from {babel} language options.

I have experienced this issue with several punctuation marks that, in French, require a space after them, and are coded in the `french` option to `babel` to do so:

```
  : ; ? !
```

However, the colon (:) is also used in `arydshln.sty`. To circumvent this, I do indeed use the solution ascribed to Till Tantau:

\shorthandoff{:}

I also extend that to the semi-colon, question mark, and exclamation mark in French-lang. journals which do NOT want that trailing space:

\shorthandoff{;}
   \shorthandoff{?}
   \shorthandoff{!}

Currently, I'm learning to incorporate tikz code into the CJL macros (Cdn. Jrnl. of Ling.) and have found I can get around the shared use of > by adding this

```
\shorthandoff{>}
```

not WITHIN the `tikzpicture` environment but just before -- but still within the outer `figure` environment.

Comment: Please also see this one to make it easier for your picture declarations http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option/86025#86025

Answer (score 1):

I solved with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]                                                           
\node[draw, circle] (1) {1};                                                         
\node[draw, circle] (2) [ right of=1] {2};                                           

\begin{scope}[-stealth]                                                              
\path (1) edge (2);                                                                  
\end{scope}                                                                          
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Using `\path [-stealth] (1) edge (2);` works just fine without requiring the extra `scope`. I would recommend you upgrade your packages.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening, I am using this approach which doesn't affect active characters outside the TikZ environment, if needed. I would add this command in the document body for Spanish.

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture={\catcode`\>=12\catcode`\<=12}}}
```

I usually don't use `\shorthandoff` command because it is unclear if `babel` package is loaded or not. If I need active characters, e.g. inside the TikZ nodes, I would use:

```
\node{\catcode`\<=13\catcode`\>=13 <<Hello>>};
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture={\catcode`\>=12\catcode`\<=12}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                 
\node[draw,circle] (1) {1};
\node[draw,circle] (2) [right of=1] {2};
\node[draw,circle,xshift=1cm,inner sep=0pt](3)[right of=2]{\catcode`\<=13\catcode`\>=13 <<Hello>>};
\path[<->] (1) edge (2);
\path[>-<] (2) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}\par
<<Hello, World!>>
\end{document}
```

[image: A small example to test the mentioned approach]