# tkz-fct, babel and tabular compiling issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, tkz-fct

I want to draw a function using pkz-fct and to save the picture with a "savebox"
here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
Test :

\newsavebox{\imgA}
\savebox{\imgA}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.,xmax=3.,ymin=-3, ymax=1.5]
\tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle, size = 3, color=black, fill=lightgray]
\tkzGrid[sub]
\tkzAxeXY
% \tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=blue, domain=-2:4]{(-2.)*(x-1.)**2-1.} % not working with Babel
\tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=blue]{(-2.)*(x-1.)**2-1.} % working with Babel
\tkzText[draw,fill = brown!20](2,1){$\Delta<0$}
\end{tikzpicture}}  
\usebox{\imgA}
\end{document}
```

I don't know where exactly the problem is, but the document doesn't compile if i use simultaneously **babel** + **(domain in tkzFct)** inside a **savebox environment**.

Can anybody help ? (the error is the same when using a tabular environment instead of savebox)

Thanks in advance.

Here is part of log :

```
! Argument of \pgfkeys@code has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.28 \end{tikzpicture}}

Runaway argument?
\tkz@bb ]function{((-2.)*(x-1.)**2-1.)/\tkz@init@ystep };\end {scope}\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@code was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.28 \end{tikzpicture}}

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }

l.28 \end{tikzpicture}}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.30 \end{document}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end{document}

[1{/home/test/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifcsname on line 28 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 28 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 28 was incomplete)
(see the transcript file for additional information){/home/test/texlive/2014/
texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</home/test/texlive/2014/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11207 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Probably your problem is that `[french]{babel}` makes `:` active. There are different solutions to this problem. One is to use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, the other is to put `\shorthandoff{:;!?}` inside `tikzpicture`. You can search for "babel+tikz+problem".

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option

Comment: First, thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately, both solutions doesn't work. I have already tried  playing with catcodes ... with no success. May be the problem is that tkz-Fct uses gnuplot ?

Comment: You are right, the problem seems to be only with savebox + tkz-fct + babel + domain ... sorry I have no other ideas.

Comment: I get no error with TeX Live 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015. Can you tell what TeX distribution you are using?

Comment: @egreg :
I use texlive 2014 on xubuntu 14.10. The same problem is inside a tabular (tabularx, tabu) environment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `tikzpicture` inside an argument. It works if you use a `lrbox` environment instead the `\savebox` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}% loads graphicx, xcolor

\begin{document}
Test :

\newsavebox\imgA
\begin{lrbox}{\imgA}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1.,xmax=3.,ymin=-3, ymax=1.5]
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle, size = 3, color=black, fill=lightgray]
    \tkzGrid[sub]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=blue, domain=-2:4]{(-2.)*(x-1.)**2-1.}
    \tkzText[draw,fill = brown!20](2,1){$\Delta<0$}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
\usebox{\imgA}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is using `\shorthandoff{:}\savebox{imgA}{...}\shorthandon{:}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
Test :

\newsavebox{\imgA}
\shorthandoff{:}
\savebox{\imgA}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1.,xmax=3.,ymin=-3, ymax=1.5]
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle, size = 3, color=black, fill=lightgray]
    \tkzGrid[sub]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=blue, domain=-2:4]{(-2.)*(x-1.)**2-1.}
    \tkzText[draw,fill = brown!20](2,1){$\Delta<0$}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\shorthandon{:}
\usebox{\imgA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Now it works fine. Thank you for the fix.