# use pgtgantt with babel package in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, babel, pgfgantt

I would like to fit a gantt chart in a beamer frame with the babel package loaded with French language.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Gantt charts}
\begin{ganttchart}[
x unit=0.22cm,
y unit title=0.5cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
title label font=\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont,
bar label font=\tiny,
group label font=\tiny\bfseries,
milestone label font=\tiny\itshape,
]{1}{40}
\gantttitle{2020}{4}
\gantttitle{2021}{12}
\gantttitle{2022}{12}
\gantttitle{2023}{12}
\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,40}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Groupe 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Tâche 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Tâche 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Publication}{7} \ganttnewline \\
\ganttbar{Tâche 3}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

\end{frame}
```

Babel is not working with pgfgantt in a beamer frame ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! Could you be so kind and clarify what you mean when you say it "is not working"? I just tried compiling your example, and I'm not seeing any obvious issues.

Comment: Hi ! it's strange... on my computer I have 2 compilations errors : "Package tikz error + or - expected "and" Package tikz error Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?"

Comment: Hmm, what does the log file say? Anything preceding those messages? Also, what TeX compiler are you using?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289852/package-tikz-error-with-pgfgantt with the answer in comments, pointing to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option/ so it is a bit difficult to close. Anyway, the solution is to put `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` directly below `\usepackage{pgfgantt}`.

Comment: Or alternatively, if you don't want to use the tikzlibrary for some reason, you can put `\shorthandoff{:;!}` in your Gantt chart, just before the first `\gantttitle`.

Comment: I have already try to use ```\usetikzlibrary{babel}```, it works for an article document but not for a beamer... The other solution proposed (```\shorthandoff{:;!}```) works perfectly !! Thanks !!