# TikZ & Babel incompatibility

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, compilation-error

The following M(not)WE works without the importation of `babel`. How can I fix this ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[french]{babel,varioref}

\newcommand\commentthis[3]{
    \coordinate (M) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$); 
    \path
        (M.east) +(.75,0) node[right,blue]{#3}
    ;
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[
        espcl = 1.5,
    ]{
        $x$                         /1,
        Signe de\\ $-x+3$           /1.5
    }{%
         $-1$, $+1$
    }

    \tkzTabLine { z , + , z }
    \commentthis{T21}{T22}{TEST}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the log there is :

```
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 69.

./tab-sign-deco.tex:77: Package tikz Error: + or - expected.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77     \signline{T21}{T22}{$3$}
                                 
? 
./tab-sign-deco.tex:77: Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77     \signline{T21}{T22}{$3$}
                                 
End of file on the terminal!
```

Comment: Did you already try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`? See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86023/134144

Comment: I didn't know this library. This fixes the problem. Thanks for this and alos for the froggy link !