# How to take out two arrows from the same line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of available TikZ libraries with a short introduction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction)
>   [Multiple arrows between nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57285/multiple-arrows-between-nodes)

I am new to tikz. I want to know how to draw this kind(given in the figure) of arrows? And how to put common input lines for two buffers? I want to draw something like this :

[image]

Comment: I think a good starting point for this could be [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57285/multiple-arrows-between-nodes); moreover you will find more link related to similar stuff in the comments.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42679/5239

Comment: This question lists a few different arrows types: [Graph into graph with arrows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/graph-into-graph-with-arrows/34127#34127), and for resizing arrows see [meta arrow tips](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29485/meta-arrow-tips/30407#30407).